# How to read post data in Symfony

Tags: symfony

For some reason the request data isn't being picked up by Symfony, but I can see it in `$_POST`. I'm probably missing something obvious, any ideas are welcome.

Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

    $defectType = $request->query->get('defectType');
    $defectDescription = $request->query->get('defectDescription');
    $defectPhoto = $request->files->get('defectPhoto');

    var_dump($_POST); 
    var_dump($defectDescription);
```

Here's the output:

```
array (size=2)
  'defectType' => string 'Critical' (length=8)
  'defectDescription' => string 'test' (length=4)

null
```

Comment: Look at the `Request class`, at the top you will see which attribute embed the global vars:  ` /**
     * Request body parameters ($_POST).
     *
     * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag
     */
    public $request;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `query` bag is for `$_GET` parameters. `$_POST` is saved in the `request` bag.

```
$request->request->get('foo');
```

Comment: Thanks - that was it.